# Prompting for MySQLDump password in a bash script?

Tags: bash, mysql

I'm trying to write a bash script that runs a `mysqldump` command that uses the `-p` flag. This flag prompts the user for a password, which works as expected when run in the shell directly, but does not appear when run in a script.

```
#!/usr/bin/env 

ssh user@domain.com 'mysqldump -u mysqluser -p --databases foo | bzip2' > ~/temp/foo-dump.sql.bz2
```

Now I could embed the password in the script or pass it as an arguments, but I really want the script to prompt the user for the password so the password doesn't show up in my scripts repo or in my bash history.

Anyone have any idea on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
read -p "mysql password: " PASS && ssh user@domain.com 'mysqldump -u mysqluser -p'$PASS' --databases foo | bzip2' > foo-dump.sql.bz2 ; PASS=""
```

In this case, you will first enter the mysql password, and then be prompted for the ssh password. Note that the mysql password will not be hidden, i.e., someone can read it over your shoulder. If you want to avoid that, use the flag `-s`

```
read -s -p "mysql password: " PASS && ...
```

Note also that there mustn't be any space between the "p" (in -p for password) and the quotation mark for the password variable.

Also, your shebang is not specifying which interpreter to use, which might be a problem. I'd suggest you use `#!/bin/bash` or `#!/usr/bin/env bash`.

Comment: Hmm, didn't work. I can enter text after running the script, but it's not an explicit promit and the script doesn't process to the actual dump.

Comment: I've added an explicit prompt for mysql password. Why do you say "the script doesn't process the actual dump"? what is happening? it gives you an empty file? it throws an error?

Comment: I'm sorry, I still don't understand what kind of problem you're having. Just by redirecting to a file (`> foo-dump.sql.bz2`) should create an empty file, even if the command for ssh failed. Is there any other clue you could give me?

Comment: wait, I know. I proposed an `&&`, which means if the first command (the `read`) fails the second command (the `ssh`) won't be executed. It's possible that your read is failing, although I don't know why...

Comment: I tried creating a bash script to run it. If I use `#!/bin/sh` or `#!/bin/bash` it works fine, but with `#!/usr/bin/env` it doesn't prompt me. `read` (as I'm using here) is a built-in command from bash. Is there a reason for you to use `#!/usr/bin/env`?

Comment: @JamesMcMahon check my new comments :)

Comment: ha, sorry, launch week so I am distracted by other things, but I will circle back to this when I get a chance

Comment: Finally got circled back this and got a chance to try out your suggestions. It all worked, thank you.

Comment: thanks, I was very curious to know if that was the problem. (y)